# Rspec can't stub where or find_by_, only find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails, stub

I'm going to share several pairs of run code and test code. Basically, the test code is only working when I use a `find` on the object class, but the problem is `find` is the one method I DON'T want to use because I'm not looking for the primary key!

**Approach 1**: stubbing `:where` with `Plan.all` so that first can be called on it

```
#run code
@current_plan = Plan.where(stripe_subscription_id: event.data.object.lines.data.first.id).first

#test code
@plan = Plan.new #so this is the first Plan that I'd like to find
Plan.stub(:where).and_return(Plan.all)

#result of @current_plan (expecting @plan)
=> nil
```

**Approach 2**: chain stubbing `:where` and `:first`

```
#run code
@current_plan = Plan.where(stripe_subscription_id: event.data.object.lines.data.first.id).first

#test code
@plan = Plan.new #so this is the first Plan that I'd like to find
Plan.stub_chain(:where, :first).and_return(@plan)

#result of @current_plan (expecting @plan)
=> nil
```

**Approach 3**: stubbing custom `:find_by`

```
#run code
@current_plan = Plan.find_by_stripe_subscription_id(event.data.object.lines.data.first.id)

#test code
@plan = Plan.new
Plan.stub(:find_by_stripe_subscription_id).and_return(@plan)

#result of @current_plan (expecting @plan)
=> nil
```

**Approach 4**: stubbing `:find` WORKS! But I can't find by primary key... so I ideally need approach 3 to work...

```
#run code
@current_plan = Plan.find(2) #for giggles, to make sure the stub is ignoring the 2 argument

#test code
@plan = Plan.new
Plan.stub(:find).and_return(@plan)

#result of @current_plan (expecting @plan)
=> @plan
```

I guess another answer would be how can I creatively use `:find` with arguments, even though I understand this isn't best practice...

Comment: It's difficult to see what is happening here without seeing at least one complete example that illustrates the problem. Could it be that the code that sets the value of `@current_plan` is never executed?

Comment: I'm happy to add more code if you think it would be helpful, but I use approach 4 as a benchmark to say, this approach is working just fine, why aren't the rest. Literally the difference between teh approaches is I'm just switching out code. Let me know if you want to see more code

Comment: You might try adding an expectation to see that the method you are stubbing is actually called. I don't see any reason why you should be able to stub :find but not :find_by.

Comment: Yup I tried that. All the standard methods (find, where, etc.) are being received. `Find_by_stripe_subscription_id` is not... I think the Rspec matcher just doesn't work with custom `find_by`. Anyway, even for the `where` method though, the fact that it is being successfully retrieved is not helping the fact that it is not stubbing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have a temporary solution, which is just to use select. I.e.,

```
#run code
@current_plan = Plan.select { |p| p.stripe_subscription_id == event.data.object.lines.data.first.id }.first

#test code
@plan = Plan.new
Plan.stub_chain(:select, :first).and_return(@plan)

#result of @current_plan (expecting @plan)
=> @plan
```

Still though... if others have thoughts please chime in... I'm now a little academically curious as to why the `where` or `where, first` stubs aren't working.

The `find_by_stripe_subscription_id`, I've done some more testing, and even the expectations of methods fail on custom `find_by` methods so of course a stub won't work. BUT, see zetetic's answer below, and maybe it's just me the gods hate...

Answer (score 2):

You can stub those methods. All these tests pass:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Foo, type: :model do
  let(:foo) { double(name: "foo") }

  it "works with find" do
    expect(Foo).to receive(:find).and_return(foo)
    expect(Foo.find(1)).to eq foo
   end

  it "works with find_by" do
    expect(Foo).to receive(:find_by_name).and_return(foo)
    expect(Foo.find_by_name("foo")).to eq foo
  end

  it "works with where" do
    expect(Foo).to receive(:where).and_return([ foo ])
    expect(Foo.where(name: "foo")).to eq [foo]
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmm... ok... so I don't know what to say. Something might be wrong somewhere, but I honestly have no idea where and what. Thanks for this though.